# Use combineByKey to get output as (key, iterable[values])

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, rdd

I am trying to transform `RDD(key,value)` to `RDD(key,iterable[value])`, same as  output returned by the `groupByKey` method. 
But as `groupByKey` is not efficient, I am trying to use `combineByKey` on the  RDD instead, however, it is not working. Below is the code used:

```
val data= List("abc,2017-10-04,15.2",
          "abc,2017-10-03,19.67", 
          "abc,2017-10-02,19.8",
          "xyz,2017-10-09,46.9", 
          "xyz,2017-10-08,48.4",
          "xyz,2017-10-07,87.5", 
          "xyz,2017-10-04,83.03", 
          "xyz,2017-10-03,83.41",
          "pqr,2017-09-30,18.18", 
          "pqr,2017-09-27,18.2", 
          "pqr,2017-09-26,19.2", 
          "pqr,2017-09-25,19.47", 
          "abc,2017-07-19,96.60",
          "abc,2017-07-18,91.68", 
          "abc,2017-07-17,91.55")
val rdd = sc.parallelize(templines)
val rows = rdd.map(line => {
  val row = line.split(",")
  ((row(0), row(1)), row(2))
})

// re partition and sort based key    
val op = rows.repartitionAndSortWithinPartitions(new CustomPartitioner(4))
val temp = op.map(f => (f._1._1, (f._1._2, f._2)))

val mergeCombiners = (t1: (String, List[String]), t2: (String, List[String])) => 
    (t1._1 + t2._1, t1._2.++(t2._2))
val mergeValue = (x: (String, List[String]), y: (String, String)) => {
  val a = x._2.+:(y._2)
  (x._1, a)
}

// createCombiner, mergeValue, mergeCombiners
val x = temp.combineByKey(
  (t1: String, t2: String) => (t1, List(t2)),
  mergeValue,
  mergeCombiners)
```

`temp.combineByKey` is giving compile time error, I am not able to get it.

Comment: What are trying to do? sample output for given input?

Answer (score 3):

If you want a output similar from what `groupByKey` will give you, then you should absolutely use `groupByKey` and not some other method. The `reduceByKey`, `combineByKey`, etc. are only more efficient compared to using `groupByKey` followed with an aggregation (giving you the same result as one of the other `groupBy` methods could have given).

As the wanted result is an `RDD[key,iterable[value]]`, building the list yourself or letting `groupByKey` do it will result in the same amount of work. There is no need to reimplement `groupByKey` yourself. The problem with `groupByKey` is not its implementation but lies in the distributed architecture.

For more information regarding `groupByKey` and these types of optimizations, I would recommend reading more [here](https://github.com/awesome-spark/spark-gotchas/blob/master/04_rdd_actions_and_transformations_by_example.md#be-smart-about-groupbykey).